# WPF window won't appear when using Show or ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a junior programmer.

A window of my WPF program won't show itself anymore. I can't seem to find out why.

My program has three different windows. When the first one shows up and I click on the button to start the rest of the program, it does run, it also goes through the code of the window that I want to see, but it does not show anything.

I hope that any of you can help.

Below are parts of my code. The first one should already call the window

```
private void SortingPartOne(){
    Function rename = new Function();
    rename.wrkLocTree.CurrentDirectory = StartingPath;
    rename.wrkLocTree.GiveUpdatePerFolder();
    rename.wrkLocTree.Show();
```

The second part creates a new class and also should 'create' the window.

```
public class Function{
    public WorkLocationTree wrkLocTree = new();
```

The third part is for updating the window that won't show up

```
public void GiveUpdatePerFolder(){
    //variable declaration
    int dirCounter;
    string directoryToAdd = Path.GetFileName(CurrentDirectory);
    
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(BeginPath)) BeginPath = MainWindow.StartingPath;
    string dirs = Path.GetFileName(BeginPath) + CurrentDirectory.Replace(BeginPath, "");
    List<string> directories = dirs.Split('\\').ToList();
   dirCounter = directories.Count-1;

    // End variable declaration */

    if(!oldDirectories.Any()){
        if(_textBoxes == null || _textBoxes[0] == null) _textBoxes = new TextBox[1];
    
        _textBoxes[0] = new TextBox{ Text = directoryToAdd, Width = 250 };
        AddTextBox(0);
    }
    else{
        if(directories == oldDirectories) return;
        if(directories.Count > oldDirectories.Count){
            if(_textBoxes == null || _textBoxes[0] == null) _textBoxes = new TextBox[1];
            else{
                List<TextBox> txtBxConverter = _textBoxes.ToList();
                txtBxConverter.Add(new TextBox());
                txtBxConverter.Add(new TextBox());
                _textBoxes = txtBxConverter.ToArray();
            }
        
            _textBoxes[dirCounter] = new TextBox{ Text = directoryToAdd, Width = 100 };

            if(_lines == null || _lines[0] == null) _lines = new Line[2];
            else{
                List<Line> converter = _lines.ToList();
                converter.Add(new Line());
                converter.Add(new Line());
                _lines = converter.ToArray();
            }
        
            int lineCounter = _lines.Length > 0 ? _lines.Length : 0;
        
            _lines[lineCounter] = new Line{ VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, X1 = 0, X2 = 7.5, Stroke = Brushes.Chocolate, StrokeThickness = 3 };
            _lines[lineCounter + 1] = new Line{ VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, Y1 = -14, Y2 = 1.5, Stroke = Brushes.Chocolate, StrokeThickness = 3 };
        
            AddLine(dirCounter, lineCounter);
            AddTextBox(dirCounter);
        }
        else if(directories.Count < oldDirectories.Count){
            ClearLayer(dirCounter, 2);
            _textBoxes[directories.Count - 1].Text = directoryToAdd;
            AddTextBox(dirCounter);
        }
        else if(directories.Count == oldDirectories.Count){
            if(directories[directories.Count-1] == oldDirectories[directories.Count-1]){
                return;
            }
            ClearLayer(dirCounter, 1);
            _textBoxes[dirCounter].Text = directoryToAdd;
            AddTextBox(dirCounter);
        }
    }
    oldDirectories.RemoveRange(0, oldDirectories.Count);
    for(int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++){
        oldDirectories.Add(directories[i]);
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

There's also a small part where the textboxes get added to the Stack panels. But I don't think that it would be necessary to share

Comment: Your problem may be that you are not adding the UIElements that you are creating to the view. ¿What does the AddTextBox method does? ¿Does it add the textbox passed as paramater to the Window view as a child of it?

Comment: @JorgeFernandezHerrero The AddTextBox function is a switch that adds a System.Windows,Controls TextBox as a child to a StackPanel

Comment: Then it may be that the bindings are not correctly set. It is hard to say jsut looking at this code.